# How to model straps

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, shrinkwrap

Can anyone help me by suggesting a technique to model arm\leg restraints. What i mean is a technique to actually wrap them around the arm of a chair. I can actually model the straps myself but how would i go about wrapping them around the arm of my chair?. Would a bezier curve do the trick or is there a better way?.

---

I'm looking to wrap straps like these ones around the arm of a chair[image]

Comment: hello, maybe show pictures as close as possible to what you'd like to do, but maybe this kind of tuto will help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ys_8P9Et28I

Answer (score 1):

You can use curve with custom section.

(Use the tilt button to rotate points.)

[image]

[image]